# What's the difference between failover and takeover in ha?

Tags: high-availability

The two concepts seems so simlar,is there and difference between them?
What kind of occasions did they referenced to?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen them used interchangably, so some confusion exists. This is how I use them:

Takeover is normally a dynamic action, associated with an Active / Active configuration, which can have minimal or no outage impact for one Active Node to takeover pending or in-progress work from the other (failed) Active node.

Failover is normally associated with an Active / Passive configuration, implying some level of automated or manual action being required for the Passive node to begin processing work, if the Active node fails.